# Geolocation display function unresponsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

Currently in the process of building a local weather display application; I figured I'd start by writing a function that retrieves and then displays the acquired geolocation data just to test that I was actually getting it. [This](http://codepen.io/elemkeh/pen/mOXPGJ) CodePen is what I've got so far. Here's the relevant JavaScript (note that jQuery is loade in the pen):

```
function giveResponse(res){
  document.getElementByID("cond").innerHTML = res;
}

function getLoc(){
  var response;

  if('geolocation' in navigator) {
    requestlocation();
  }
  else {
    response = "Geolocation not supported by your browser."
    giveResponse(response);
  }
  function reqLoc() {
    var options = {
      enableHighAccuracy: false,
      timeout:5000,
      maximumAge:0
    };

    function success(pos){
      var lng = pos.coords.longitude;
      var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
      response = "Your location is " + lng + lat + " .";
      giveResponse(response);
    }

    function error(err){
      response = "There was an error retrieving your location."
      giveResponse(response);
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);

  }

}

$(document).ready(function(){
  getLoc();
});
```

As you can see from the pen, the cond element isn't showing the error behavior I described, or any behavior at all. What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

F12 console shows that `requestlocation()` is not defined.  Either rename function `reqLoc()` to `requestlocation()` (if that is appropriate), or define `requestlocation()` in scope.

[image: error]